# Relative perimittivity of conductor?

Tags: electricity, electric-current, dielectric

Why is the relative permittivity $\epsilon_r$ infinite for a conductor?

Where does it come from mathematically and does it make physical sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such rule.

In a conductive material, the permittivity will be a complex number,

$\epsilon = \epsilon' + i\frac{\sigma}{\omega}$,

where $\epsilon'$ is the real part of permittivity, $\sigma$ is the material conductivity, and $\omega$ is the frequency being considered.

In a perfect conductor, of course, $\sigma=\infty$, and so $|\epsilon|$ goes to infinity as well. But there is no such rule for conductive materials in general.